# Make context menu submenu per user in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, contextmenu, explorer

I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885143/6461649) to create a submenu with some custom commands in Windows Explorer, but need to do everything inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. While I am able to create the submenu within that contact, I can't find a way to create the subcommands in such a way.

The answer says they should be in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell`, so I tried what I thought would be the user equivalent `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to create these subcommands so Explorer finds them within the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works without having to add entries into non-user-writable registry locations:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\testmenu]
    "MUIVerb"="Nice Name"
    "subcommands"=""
    "Icon"="c:\\path\\to\\icon.ico"
```

Note the `subcommands` entry with an empty string value, this seems important.

For any subcommands to appear in the menu, add the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\testmenu\Shell\subcommandname]
    @="Nice Name of Subcommand"
    "Icon"="c:\\path\\to\\another_icon.ico"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\testmenu\Shell\subcommandname\command]
    @="c:\path\to\command.exe"
```

This would place the submenu for directories in the left-hand pane in Explorer, for the main window use the base path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell` and for files use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell`